# Найти дату, которая была N дней назад

Tags: javascript, html

Найти дату, которая была N дней назад (значение вводит пользователь в текстовое поле, N может быть отрицательным).

```js
var task03Btn = document.getElementById("task03Btn");
var task03Result = document.getElementById("task03Result");

task03Btn.addEventListener("click", function GetMinusDate(date, days) {
  var CopyDate = new Date(date);
  days = document.getElementById('daysAgo').value;

  CopyDate.setDate(date.getDate() - days);
  return CopyDate.getDate();
  task03Result.innerHTML = `${GetMinusDate(date, days)}<br>`;
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> Задача №2. День месяца был N дней назад </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="daysAgo" placeholder="дней" />
      <button id="task03Btn"> Выполнить </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="task03Result"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var task03Btn = document.getElementById("task03Btn");
var task03Result = document.getElementById("task03Result");

task03Btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var CopyDate = new Date();
  var days = document.getElementById('daysAgo').value;

  // вычитаем days из дней CopyDate
  CopyDate.setDate(CopyDate.getDate() - days);
  //return CopyDate.getDate(); // после return исполнение кода закончивается
  task03Result.innerHTML = `${CopyDate}`;
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> Задача №2. День месяца был N дней назад </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="daysAgo" placeholder="дней" />
      <button id="task03Btn"> Выполнить </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="task03Result"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Можете еще подсказать как в input позволить вводить только цифры месяца (1 - 12)

Comment: @Bohdan, через аттрибуты [min и max](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-max)

Comment: cпасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

Это уже решаем домашнее задание? :)

```js
document.getElementById("task03Btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  let date = new Date() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * document.getElementById("daysAgo").value;
  document.getElementById("task03Result").innerHTML = new Date(date);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="daysAgo" placeholder="дней" />
<button id="task03Btn">Выполнить</button>
<div id="task03Result"></div>
```

Comment: Почему new Date() вместо Date.now()?

Comment: Потому что new Date().valueOf() === Date.now() // true.

Comment: Но ведь new Date().valueOf() на порядок медленнее Date.now(), и при этом жрет почти в 8 раз больше ресурсов.

Comment: Согласен. Только какая доля миллисекунды теряется? И насколько эта разница влияет на быстродействие функции когда в там дважды используется getElementById? И важно ли это в рамках задачи где надо вычесть 1 день? Не драйвер для мышки пишем.

Comment: Соглашусь, new Date или Date.now() это дело привычки. В контексте задачи не так важно, но и знать тоже полезно.